# Meaning of "chords" in a bar with eight notes

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music

First of all, LaM means AM and Sim means Bm. In the sheet music you will see below, what does mean AM________? Does it mean all the notes I will find on the _____ part will correspond to the AM chord? But if so, shouldn't it be C# instead of C?

[image]

Pic related to my comments on Tim's answer.

[image: Pic related to my comment on Tim's answer.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** C♯! The piece is in key A major, and that has its key signature at the start of the line, including a ♯ sign on the C space. It only needs to be there to tell us that every C in the piece must be C♯.

EDIT: The **key** of the piece is A major. The **chord/s** in each bar are chords formed by the notes in that bar, or the chords which can be played in that bar. In bar 12, the first half is chord E, followed by chord D.In bar 14, the first half is chord A major, followed by 4 separate notes which don't constitute a chord. Hence solfege.

There is no key change, and that E chord you mention doesn't need a D♯ note, because the piece is still in A, which has no D♯.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I didn't notice the # at the begining. I think I got it: the next bar is in key E major. Does that mean that every D is D#? Going to add a new pic to show how the piece is constantly changing of key.

Comment: What I mean is, for example, on the bar 12 of the new attached pic, the key signature is still A major, but the key showed on the bar is E major ( MiM = EM). Does that mean that the D on bar 12 is D# even if there is no sharp on D neither at the beginning (key signature) nor on the note on the bar?

Comment: Oh I see, everything is clear now. I just noticed the E chord is a power chord (G# is missing), I think that confused me a bit. Thank you so much. Regards.